Type error 'float' object is not callable when defining d2r=m.radians(1)
I have a weird scenario where theoretically a very simply line of code should not be giving errors as I've seen it work in other .py files, yet when I implement it in my own code, I get the following error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 5
      1 import math as m
      3 d2r=m.radians(1)
----> 5 x=d2r(2)
      7 print(x)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

The code I'm using is:
import math as m

d2r=m.radians(1)

x=d2r(2)

print(x)

As I said, I've seen this same code used in other people's code and their ones seem to run perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?
I've checked other people's code, e.g.text and it works perfectly fine

With d2r(2) you are trying to do a function call on the float d2r which Python does not like.

Remember to look up what the functions you call do. https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.radians would have told you everything  you needed to know to explain the problem. But even if you forget that, read the error: it's literally telling you that you're trying to use a variable that is just a floating point number in a way that only works for functions.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The error message is one of those things that doesn't make sense until one is sufficiently enlightened to understand it ... I think it's OK to indulge an inexperienced person with an explanation, even if it seems obvious to you.

Coenraad, to see what's going on, try inspecting d2r at the console; I think you'll see it's just a number. You seem to want a function to convert degrees to radians, and I think that's a very useful idea. I would write it like this: d2r = lambda d: d*math.radians(1) and then you can say d2r(2) or d2r(200) or d2r(xyz) where xyz is some number of degrees, etc.

import math as m
d2r = m.radians(1)

d2r is a float.
It is used to convert Degrees to radians
print(d2r)
#0.017453292519943295

If you want d2r(2) you have to do:
x = d2r * 2
#0.03490658503988659

Or if you want to multiply it with pi then:
m.pi * d2r
#0.05483113556160755

